# Select2 remove default option when another selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'd like to have a default option act like a placeholder.

I'm doing an ajax search for Products. I want my input box to show "All" until I've selected a product.

This will be the default view:

[image]

But as soon as I select a product, I want All to disappear and just the product to show:
[image]

I've put together a codepen to hopefully get things rolling!

Thank you all!

https://codepen.io/saltcod/pen/bGdzoGN

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <select class="form-control am-product-selector__product-list-select" name="choices-multiple-default" id="choices-multiple-default" placeholder="All Products" multiple>
    <option value="All" selected>All</option>

  </select>

</div>
```

And the JS:

```
const options = [{ id: 1, text: 'All' }];

const select2Instance = jQuery( '#choices-multiple-default' ).select2( {
        placeholder: 'Search products',
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,

            data: params => {
                return {
                    //term: params.term // search query
                };
            },

            // Process fetched results
            processResults: data => {
                if ( data ) {
                    data.map( item => {
                        options.push( { id: item.id, text: item.title } );
                    } );
                }

                return {
                    results: options
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        minimumInputLength: 3 // the minimum of symbols to input before perform a search
    } );
```

Comment: is your product multiple selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `change` event of native `select` elements and its scoped version `change.select2`.

When adding `select2` plugin on an element, the `change` event is triggered whenever an option is selected or removed.

So, when an option from the async list is added, we should remove the `all` option.
Also, when all options are deleted (the select has no value), we should re-add the `all` option.
But we need to inform the `select2` about the changes, so we trigger `change.select2` event.

The full code is:

```js
select2Instance.on('change', function () {
  const values = $(this).val();
  if (values.length > 1) {
    const index = values.indexOf('all');
    if (index > -1) {
      values.splice(index, 1);
      $(this).val(values);
    }
  } else if (values.length === 0) {
    $(this).val('all');
  }
  $(this).trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes;
});
```

Codepen demo:
https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/yLNZzbb

More info about Select2 Events:

- https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events
- https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I wonder if I could trouble you for a quick change in the way I had to achieve this? I previously had the All option in the markup, but seems I need to add it via JS instead. I've forked your pen here: https://codepen.io/saltcod/pen/YzyGmpb        Nudges in the right direction greatly appreciated!

Comment: I will try to implement it. But, do you want the 'All option' to be displayed in the search results list as well? Or just  like before?

Comment: is this pen working for you? https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/gOawVNL. `var allOptionData = {id: 'all',text: 'All'};
var allOption = new Option(allOptionData.text, allOptionData.id, true, true);
jQuery( '#choices-multiple-default').append(allOption).trigger('change');`

Comment: YES! That was exactly it!  Thank you so much for your time — very generous of you. Greatly appreciated. Thank you!!